# How to access a variable name dynamically (after creating variable name dynamically) in r

Tags: r

I want to create some variable names dynamically. After creation the variable name, I also want to use them.

For example, I want to create a variable name dynamically x_1 (at the time of i=1) and after create, I want to use this (x_1) in the next line.

```
threshold <- 0.5
length <- 2

for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('x', i, sep='_'), 1)
  assign(paste('y', i, sep='_'), x + (threshold * 0.2) - (length - 1.3)) # here I want the name (and value) of the `x` based on `i`
  assign(paste('z', i, sep='_'), y * i + 2) #here I want the name (and value) of the `y` based on `i`
}
```

I have tried different methods but getting errors. Like

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('x', i, sep='_'), 1)
  assign(paste('y', i, sep='_'), eval(paste0("x_", i) + (threshold * 0.2) - (length - 1.3))) # here I want the name (and value) of the `x` based on `i`
  assign(paste('z', i, sep='_'), eval(paste0("y_", i) * i + 2)) # here I want the name (and value) of the `y` based on `i`
}
```

Error

```
Error in paste0("x_", i) + (threshold * 0.2) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Another approach

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("DataThing$x_", i), 1)
  assign(paste0("DataThing$y_", i), DataThing[paste0("x_", i)] + (threshold * 0.2) - (length - 1.3)) # here I want the name (and value) of the `x` based on `i`
  assign(paste0("DataThing$y_", i), DataThing[paste0("y_", i)] * i + 2) # here I want the name (and value) of the `y` based on `i`
}
```

Error

```
Error in assign(paste0("DataThing$y_", i), DataThing[paste0("x_", i)] +  : 
  object 'DataThing' not found
```

Any idea, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited)
This should work:

```r
threshold <- 0.5
len <- 2

for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('x', i, sep='_'), 1)
  assign(paste('y', i, sep='_'), get(paste0("x_", i)) + (threshold * 0.2) - (len - 1.3))
  assign(paste('z', i, sep='_'), get(paste0("y_", i)) * i + 2)
}

x_1
#> [1] 1
y_1
#> [1] 0.4
z_1
#> [1] 2.4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: When trying first approach getting error `Error in paste0("x_", i) + (threshold * 0.2) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Sorry, I had missed a `)` there. I edited the answer with code that should work and added a reprex.

Comment: Thanks, I already found the missed `)` and I am using this line of code `assign(paste('y', i, sep='_'), get(eval(paste0("x_", i, sep=""))) + (threshold * 0.2) - (path_length - 1.3))`. Howver, I am accepting the answer.